# If $X$ is continuous, then $P(X = Y ) = 0.$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables on a probability space. To prove that if $X$ is continuous, then $P(X = Y ) = 0.$

Need some hint to solve the problem.

Comment: First by definition of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and independence, then by Fubini, $$P(X=Y)=\iint\mathbf 1_{x=y}dP_X(x)dP_Y(y)=\int\left(\int\mathbf 1_{x=y}dP_X(x)\right)dP_Y(y))=\int P(X=y)dP_Y(y)$$ Since $P_X$ has no atom, $P(X=y)=0$ for every $y$ hence the integral on the RHS is zero, as desired.

Comment: Your questions show a lack in providing context: what you've tried, what you think is relevant (provision of a definition of independent random variables on a probability space, and in particular, and what it means for a  variable to be continuous, any theorems you know that might relate, etc.). To simply post problem statement questions and expect others to do your work for you is not the intent of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Try calculating $\Pr(X=Y \vert Y=y)$, and use the law of iterated expectations.

Comment: but why $X$ continuous is given?

Comment: @user8795 that fact simplifies calculation I suggest above.

Comment: can you give some more hints @Theoretical Economist

Comment: This is useless without a solid definition of conditional probability in the measure theoretic sense. Kudos to @user8795 for having asked for justifications. For the canonical approach (which shows that considering conditional expectations is actually taking a step backwards rather than forward), please see my comment on main.